# Unable to access resources (images) placed in another assembly in wpf application

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, dll

I have a WPF project that has a link to another assembly that has only some resources in it (namely images and styles). The name of this assembly is Library.WPF.Resources

I can not access images in the resource assembly.

In resource assembly I included one image called but_close.png and set is property to

```
build action= content
copy to output directory = don't copy
```

In wpf application, I am using this image as follow

```
<Button  Canvas.Left="997" Canvas.Top="10" Width="16" Height="14" Style="{StaticResource TransparentButton}" x:Name="CloseWindow">
            <Image  >
                <Image.Style>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type Image}">
                        <Setter Property="Source" Value="pack://application:,,,/Library.WPF.Resources;component/Resources/Images/but_close.png"/>
                        <Style.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                                <Setter Property="Source"  Value="/Library.WPF.Resources;component/Resources/Images/but_close_roll.png"/>
                            </Trigger>
                        </Style.Triggers>
                    </Style>
                </Image.Style>
            </Image>
        </Button
```

I can not see any problem when I look at the page contain this button on wpf application (no error indicating that application can not find it. but when I run the application, I am getting this error:

```
{"Cannot locate resource 'resources/images/but_close.png'."}
```

I opened the Library.WPF.Resources.dll in a hex editor and looked for but_close.png and I could not find it in dll.

Why the image is not included in dll?

I changed the build action of but_close.png in resource project to resource. Same issue, it is not included in dll.

Changed the build action of this image to embeddedresource. Now it is in dll, but still when I run the application I am getting error that resource can not be found.

My questions:

1- What is the correct build action for images in in a resource assembly?

2- Why can I access the image in another xaml page?

Comment: Build Action must be set to `Resource`. Then rebuild everything.

Comment: @Clemens: When I set the build action to Resource, I can not see my image in dll. I opened in dll in a hex editor and looked for but_close.png, and could not find it.

Comment: @mans That's ok. Also, you have folder **Resources** in project **Library.WPF.Resources**?

Comment: @Clemens: yes I have, but I am using pack uri to point to Resources in my library assembly.

Comment: @Clemens: I moved the image directory in resource project to root, so the pack uri is : "pack://application:,,,/Library.WPF.Resources;component/Images/but_close.png" and I am getting that images/but_close.png can not be found.

Answer (score 0):

Set the build action to "resource".
Make sure the resources access modifier is "public"

Access the resource like this:

```
<Grid>
    <Image Source ="pack://application:,,,/Library.WPF;component/Resources/but_close.png" Stretch="Fill"/>
</Grid>
```

Comment: How can I set the resource access modifier to public?

Comment: Right click the project. Click "properties".
In the Resources tab you will find several combox like "Add Resource" and also the "Access Modifier"

Comment: Did you try this solution?

Comment: Yes I did test it but it did not work. The resources in properties page are windoform properties and not wpf.